# GetTimeKeeper() is not defined

Tags: python, paraview

I am getting the error

> timeKeeper1 = GetTimeKeeper()
> Error: name 'GetTimeKeeper' is not defined

My code is as follows:

```
from paraview.simple import *
timeKeeper1 = GetTimeKeeper()
```

When I run the py script in paraview, it works.
I checked the simple.py of my paraview installation, and GetTimeKeeper() does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your paraview installation, look here: [Bug#15779](https://github.com/Kitware/ParaView/commit/b6ba3281e190cd1a20e445a7427871dbee426bf5)